# Have failed to set the right condition for if() in R

Tags: r

link to my data:
https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/rprog%2Fdata%2FProgAssignment3-data.zip

Truth to be told, this is not actually my script, I got it on some sources and try to break it down and then, try to re-write it according to my knowledge.

Here is my script

```
rankhospital<- function(state, outcome, num = "best"){
        data<- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
        outcomes<- c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")
        if ( state %in% data$State == FALSE){ stop("invalid state!")}
        if (outcome %in% outcomes == FALSE){stop("invalid outcome")}
        if(num != "best" && num != "worst" && num%%1 != 0){stop("invalid num")}
        data<- data[, c(2, 7, 11, 17, 23)]
        names(data)<- list("name", "state", "heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")
        data<- data[data$State == state & data[outcome] != "Not Available", ]
        data[ , outcome] <- as.numeric(data[ , outcome ] )
        max<- nrow(data)
        if (num == "best"){num <- 1}
        if (num == "worst"){num == as.numeric(max)}
        if (num > max){ return(NA)}
        data<- data[order(data[, 1]), ]
        data<- data[order(data[,outcome]), ]
        data[num, "name"]
}
```

Requirement of this project is

> The num argument can take values “best”, “worst”, or an integer
>   indicating the ranking (smaller numbers are better). If the number
>   given by num is larger than the number of hospitals in that state,
>   then the function should return NA. Hospitals that do not have data on
>   a particular outcome should be excluded from the set of hospitals when
>   deciding the rankings.

My problem start from this part of the Script

```
max<- nrow(data)
        if (num == "best"){num <- 1}
        if (num == "worst"){num == as.numeric(max)}
        if (num > max){ return(NA)}
```

When I test the script with

```
rankhospital("MD", "heart attack", "worst")
[1] NA
```

I got "NA" for any value of argument num, even though num < max, while I should be the name of the hospital.
I did try to change
if (num > nrow(data)){ return(NA)} instead of max but it still not working. Please show me the mistake in my script and I'm sorry for the freaking long question :)

Comment: `num == as.numeric(max)` is a condition, `num <- 1` is an assignment. Do you want `num <- as.numeric(max)`? BTW, I'm pretty sure you can omit the `as.numeric()` part, as `nrow` returns an integer by default.

Comment: Thanks,when I change to num <- as.numeric(max), I got character(0), I think it's should be num == as.numeric(max)

Comment: I just do as you said but still get NA as the result

Comment: Please read in your data and copy the output of `(dput(head(data[, c(2, 7, 11, 17, 23)]))` into your question. I'm not comfortable downloading a .zip file from an unknown location.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you use `num` as a function variable in the call and later try to redefine it within the function.

The last part of your function should look like this:

```
if(num == "best"){temprow <- 1}
if(num == "worst"){temprow <- nrow(data)}
if(is.numeric(num) & num %in% 1:nrow(data)){temprow <- num}
if(is.numeric(num) & !(num %in% 1:nrow(data))){stop("ranking out of bounds!")}
data<- data[order(data[, 1]), ]
data<- data[order(data[,outcome]), ]
data[temprow, "name"]
```

Delete the row with `max <- nrow(data)`, that's unnecessary cluttering.